SMPP protocol v3 data_encoding
I'm a developer of the SMS platform.
In some moment I found that some clients send sms to my servers with incorrect encoding.
Here example what I got a few days ago:
Text of sms:

[realme]579174 est votre code de vÃ©rification. Il expire dans 5 minutes. Ne le partagez avec personne.

Encoding was set - 0x0 (GSM7 encoding)
But as we can see in content exist not latin characters Ã©. And with this characters encoding should be 0x8 (UCS2) and in this case - count of sms part should be 2.
Before I thought - the client made mistake.
But now I can see - count of such sms grows.
Why client sends such sms? Is it possible just forward it to supplier without changes? Can be a problem with calculating of the count of the parts?

If I understand your question, it looks like something - the phone, the network, the cellular provider and so on has not followed the protocol correctly.  Given the number of hops that the message has to take it's difficult to determine where the error comes from.

You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): 'vÃ©rification'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8') returns  'vérification' and vice versa: 'vérification'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252') -> 'vÃ©rification' …
